# proc sql doing a insert into within a call execute in SAS

Tags: sas

Within a data setp I am using a "call execute" like the one below:

Everything works fine except the last 2 variables mhstdtc2 and mhendtc2, these variables are num type with an informat and format of date9.

I receive a note that numeric variables are being converted to character on that line, How should the dates be inserted on the call execute statment. Thanks

I have tried removing the quotes which creates a messy call execute

```
  call execute("proc sql;
insert into leaddata values("||subjid||","||mhterm||","||mhstdtc_dtr||","||mhstdtc_dtr||","||mhstdtc_dtr||","||sitemnemonic||","||mhstdtc2||"d,"||mhendtc2||"d);quit;");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before generating code make sure you know what code you want to generate.  Looks like you are trying to generate something like this:

```
values(101,Stomach Pain,30NOV2018,15DEC2018,Clinic 47);
```

But you need to generate quotes around your character variables. Also there is no need to convert your dates into human readable date literals, just leave them as the raw number of days.

```
call execute(catx(' ','proc sql;','insert into leaddata','values('
 ,catx(',',quote(subjid),quote(mhterm),date1,number2,....)
 ,');quit;'));
```

But if you have the data in a dataset why not just insert directly from the data set?

```
insert into leaddata select subjid,mhterm,.... from have ;
```